# Directory query returns only 100 users

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk

I borrowed code from [here](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/home/announcements/listingdomainusernamesinaspreadsheet) to download directory data from my Google domain into a spreadsheet. All I changed in the code was to replace OpenByURL with OpenByID because of an invalid argument error. Now it works, except it only returns the first 100 users from my domain. I have about 1000 users total, perhaps a few more. Can I pull all of them? If not, can I at least increase the limit beyond 100? And/or how can I limit my query to a particular Organizational Unit?

My full code below:

```js
function writeToSpreadsheet(){
  var values = [];
  var users = AdminDirectory.Users.list({domain:'klht.org'}).users; //example: ignitesynergy.com
  for (var i=0; i<users.length; i++){
    values.push([users[i].name.fullName, users[i].primaryEmail]); //Look in the docs or use auto complete to see what you can access  
  }
  var spreadsheetID = '1JLDD2wm0_udmTn9ZHvdKhL_Ok3SvKYFqkBeiA1GdnYc';
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetID).getSheets()[0].getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}

//Red indicates the places you need to use your info
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum you can pull down is 500 – [maxResults](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list#maxResults)

Also add the orgUnitPath as part of a query field in your list call:

```
var users = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
                                      domain: 'klht.org',
                                      maxResults: 500,
                                      query: "orgUnitPath=/OU"
                                      }).users;
```

part of the returned object will be a `nextPageToken` you can add this into a follow-on query or queries until you have all your users

```
 var usersPage2 = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
                                      domain: 'klht.org',
                                      maxResults: 500,
                                      query: "orgUnitPath=/OU",
                                      pageToken: nextPageToken
                                      }).users;
```

Comment: Thank you! I've gotten the OU to work. Can you help me make the nextpagetoken trick work? Simply pasting it below my code from above resulted in "ReferenceError: "nextPageToken" is not defined. (line 13, file "Code")".  '

Comment: @TedParker - if you have a new question, please do make it a new question. Refer back to this one if it helps set context.

Comment: nextPageToken is a property of the first query. if you do not directly assign the `.users` property to `var users` you can access it. `AdminDirectory.Users.list({
                                      domain: 'klht.org',
                                      maxResults: 500,
                                      query: "orgUnitPath=/OU"
                                      }).pageToken;`

Comment: see the fuller answer to your other question to see how to recursively check for all users in the stack. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34419185/1100265